# how to check if an input is a number

Tags: lua

How do I check if an input is a number? My theory is like this:

```
local isNumber = tonumber(arg[1])

if isNumber then
print"This is sure a number"
else
print"This is not a number"
end
```

So, what you think?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Your code seems to do what you describe perfectly. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arg[1]` represents a number if `tonumber(arg[1])` does not return nil. So this would for example also work for a string `"1"`

If you want to make sure it is a number value check `type(arg[1]) == "number"`

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-tonumber

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-type

Comment: If `arg` is the array with the command line arguments, then all entries are strings..

Answer (score 1):

And if you wanna know if a number is a integer or a floating point number use `math.type()`

```
> type(math.pi) -- Normal
number
> math.type(math.pi) -- Extended
float
> math.type(math.maxinteger) -- Never puts out only "number"
integer
-- For checking with pcall() and assert() do
> do
>> local rc,res=pcall(assert,math.type(math.pi)=='float')
>> if rc and res then
>> return math.deg(math.pi),rc,res
>> else
>> error('Try something else')
>> end
>> end
180.0   true    true
```

The last `do ... end` block shows the Lua equivalent of the "Try/Catch" exception handling known from other languages.

Answer (score -1):

```
local isNumber = arg[1]
if type(isNumber) ~= "number" then isNumber = tonumber(isNumber) end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].